# R: Wrapping t.test in a function

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyeval

Why does this function fail to execute?

```
my_ttest <- function(df, variable, by){
    variable <- enquo(variable)
    by <- enquo(by)

    t.test(!!variable ~ !!by, df)
}
```

> my_ttest(mtcars, mpg, am)
>       Error in is_quosure(e2) : argument "e2" is missing, with no default

But this one works

```
my_mean <- function(df, variable, by){
        variable <- enquo(variable)
        by <- enquo(by)

        df %>% group_by(!!by) %>% summarize(mean(!!variable))
}



my_mean(mtcars, mpg, am)
# A tibble: 2 x 2
     am `mean(mpg)`
  <dbl>       <dbl>
1     0        17.1
2     1        24.4
```

(dplyr_0.8.0.1)

Comment: `t.test` is a base R function and doesn't know how to deal with quoted variables. You can use `t.test(formula(substitute(variable ~ by)), df)` without `enquo`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we want to pass the arguments separately in 'my_ttest' and construct a formula inside the function, convert the quosure (`enquo`) to a symbol (`sym`) for both 'variable', 'by', then construct the expression ('expr1') and `eval`uate` it

```
my_ttest <- function(df, variable, by, env = parent.frame()){
    variable <- rlang::sym(rlang::as_label(rlang::enquo(variable)))
    by <- rlang::sym(rlang::as_label(rlang::enquo(by)))

    exp1 <- rlang::expr(!! variable ~ !! by)



    t.test(formula = eval(exp1), data = df)

}


my_ttest(mtcars, mpg, am)
#Welch Two Sample t-test

#data:  mpg by am
#t = -3.7671, df = 18.332, p-value = 0.001374
#alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
#95 percent confidence interval:
# -11.280194  -3.209684
#sample estimates:
#mean in group 0 mean in group 1 
#       17.14737        24.39231
```

---

Or as @lionel mentioned in the comments, it can be done directly with `ensym`

```
my_ttest <- function(df, variable, by, env = parent.frame()){  

  exp1 <- expr(!!ensym(variable) ~ !!ensym(by))

    t.test(formula = eval(exp1), data = df)

  }


my_ttest(mtcars, mpg, am)
```

EDIT: Based on @lionel's comments

Comment: Hi Akrun. I see you posting solutions with `quo_name()` regularly. Please note that `quo_name()` will be deprecated at some point (at least one year in the future). Could you take a look at `?as_name` / `?as_label` from rlang 0.3.1 please.

Comment: It doesn't really make sense to convert quosures to symbol, better take the symbol directly with `ensym()`. Also note that quosures can contain arbitrary objects. Use `as_name()` to convert it as a string if you expect it to contain a symbol, or `as_label()` otherwise.

Comment: @lionel Thank you for the comments.  the `as_label` way works.  Can you post an answer with `ensym`.  Currently I am using `variable <- rlang::sym(rlang::as_label(rlang::enquo(variable)));
    by <- rlang::sym(rlang::as_label(rlang::enquo(by)))` and then the rest is the same as in the function

Comment: With `ensym()` this is just `exp1 <- expr(!!ensym(variable) ~ !!ensym(by))`. Thanks you for the update. I would change the code inline so it doesn't mention `quo_name()` at all though. It's also our fault because we're slow at updating our own documentation :(

Answer (score 3):

Not every function (and package) works with tidy evaluation. `t.test` takes either numeric vectors `x,y` as arguments or a formula. In your example, you can provide the formula and the data frame, though it does't actually seem more efficient than calling `t.test` directly.

```r
my_ttest <- function(df, frma) {
  t.test(frma, df)
}

my_ttest(mtcars, mpg ~ am)
#> 
#>  Welch Two Sample t-test
#> 
#> data:  mpg by am
#> t = -3.7671, df = 18.332, p-value = 0.001374
#> alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
#> 95 percent confidence interval:
#>  -11.280194  -3.209684
#> sample estimates:
#> mean in group 0 mean in group 1 
#>        17.14737        24.39231
```

<sup>Created on 2019-03-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>